# AttributeError: getfeature_names not found ; using scikit-learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, tf-idf

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
vectorizer = vectorizer.fit(word_data)
freq_term_mat = vectorizer.transform(word_data)

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer

tfidf = TfidfTransformer(norm="l2")
tfidf = tfidf.fit(freq_term_mat)
Ttf_idf_matrix = tfidf.transform(freq_term_mat)

voc_words = Ttf_idf_matrix.getfeature_names()
print "The num of words = ",len(voc_words)
```

when I run the program containing this piece of code I get following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "vectorize_text.py", line 87, in 
>        voc_words = Ttf_idf_matrix.getfeature_names()
>   File "/home/farheen/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-  >packages/scipy/sparse/base.py", line 499, in **getattr**
>   raise AttributeError(attr + " not found")
>   AttributeError: get_feature_names not found

Please suggest me a solution for it.

Answer (score 10):

I see two problems with your code. First, you are applying get_feature_names() to your matrix output, rather than to the vectorizer. You need to apply it to the vectorizer. Second, you are unnecessarily breaking this apart into too many steps. You can use TfidfVectorizer.fit_transform() to do what you want in much less space. Try this:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
transformed = vectorizer.fit_transform(word_data)
print "Num words:", len(vectorizer.get_feature_names())
```

Answer (score 2):

Is it not `get_feature_names()`, ie. with an underscore after 'get'.

Also, I am not sure what you are trying to do, but get_feature_names is a method valid only for *Vectorizer classes, not with the TfidTransformer.
Maybe you want TfidVectorizer instead?

Comment: Thanks for telling that .I did typo error(corrected to get_feature_names()) but that's not the problem.

Comment: I have already  tried to use get_feature_names with Vectorizer class. See the code                                                                                                                     vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
   ` vectorizer = vectorizer.fit(word_data)
    freq_term_mat = vectorizer.transform(word_data)
    voc_words =  freq_term_mat.get_feature_names()  `                          But with with same     error    >AttributeError: get_feature_names not found

Comment: Sorry, your code doesn't show that way above. Please modify/edit so you can clarify the error.

From your comments above, it doesn't look like you are using the attribute properly. Is freq_term_mat of CountVectorizer class? Doesn't look like it.

Comment: vectorizer = CountVectorizer()

Comment: vectorizer = vectorizer.fit(word_data)

Comment: freq_term_mat = vectorizer.transform(word_data)

Comment: voc_words = freq_term_mat.get_feature_names()

Comment: I am still getting the same error >AttributeError: get_feature_names not found

Comment: Right, as I said, freq_term_mat is not a CountVectorizer, is it? You transformed from vectorizer, yielding a sparse matrix of some sort, I think.

Answer (score 2):

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
TfIdfer = TfidfVectorizer(stop_words = 'english')
TfIdfer.fit_transform(word_data).toarray()
names = TfIdfer.get_feature_names()
```

Comment: Consider adding some explanations on what your code does and why it answers the question.

Answer (score -1):

You should change `get_feature_names()` to `get_feature_names_out()`.

Comment: I do not see how this answers the question at the top of this page, but it should. Please [edit] according to [answer] or delete the answer. Otherwise it risks being flagged as "not an answer" and being deleted.