# Merging two scipy.sparse matrices

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

I have two `scipy.sparse.csr_matrix` objects, `A` and `B`, as shown below:

```
print type(A)
print type(B)
print A.shape
print B.shape

<class 'scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix'>
<class 'scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix'>
(2069, 1735)
(12, 52)
```

`A` has 1735 features and `B` is has 52 features.

How can I convert `B` such that it has 1735 features (the initial 52 features should merge with `A`'s features, if there are any common features)?

For example:

```
A.get_feature_names=['S','D','F','G']
B.get_feature_names=['F','G','H','J','k']

B=[(0,0),(0,1),(1,2),(2,3),(3,4)]
```

Now I want `B` like:

```
B.get_feature_names=['S','D','F','G']

B=[(0,2),(0,3)]
```

Comment: Why is it important that they are sparse? I don't see how you could concatenate matrices that are not the same size

Comment: it is required for some NLP algorithm..

Comment: Can you give us a little more context then please?

Comment: What is the correspondence between the rows of `A` and the rows of `B`?

Comment: Where does `get_feature_names` come from?  That's not a normal method of a `scipy.sparse` matrix.

Comment: These are `scikit_learn` matrices, not plain scipy sparse ones.  That kit adds the `get_feature_names` method.  You need to dig into that package's documentation.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/32802611/901925